# Saving multiple entity with Symfony

Tags: symfony, entities

I have an error when i save multiple entities.
I have to save an invoice with :
The date
The client selection
The multiple products selection with price and quantity

For the date and the client, i haven't any errors.
But when i want to save products, i have this error :

> Neither the property "product" nor one of the methods "getProduct()",
>   "product()", "isProduct()", "hasProduct()", "__get()" exist and have
>   public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\Invoice".

If i dump the request in the controller, i have this:

> [ createdAt => 2016-05-19, client => 1, products => [ 0 => [ product
>   => 1, quantity => 1, price => 15 ] ]

Notice: The client 1 and the product 1 exists.

Here is my Invoice entity :

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Invoice
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="invoice")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\InvoiceRepository")
 */
class Invoice
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->insertedAt = new \DateTime();
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
        $this->products = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="numero", type="integer")
     */
    private $numero;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="date")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="reference", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $reference;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="pdf", type="string", length=255, unique=true, nullable=true)
     */
    private $pdf;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="paid_at", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $paidAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="inserted_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $insertedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $client;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="InvoiceStatus")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Currency")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $currency;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="InvoiceProduct", mappedBy="invoice", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $products;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set numero & reference
     *
     * @param integer $numero
     *
     * @return Invoice
     */
    public function setNumero($numero)
    {
        $this->numero = $numero;
        $this->reference = $this->createdAt->format('ym').'-'.str_pad($this->numero, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get numero
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getNumero()
    {
        return $this->numero;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     *
     * @return Invoice
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Get dueAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDueAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt->add(new \DateInterval('P30D'));
    }

    /**
     * Set reference
     *
     * @param string $reference
     *
     * @return Invoice
     */
    public function setReference($reference)
    {
        $this->reference = $reference;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get reference
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReference()
    {
        return $this->reference;
    }

    /**
     * Set paidAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $paidAt
     *
     * @return Invoice
     */
    public function setPaidAt($paidAt)
    {
        $this->paidAt = $paidAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get paidAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getPaidAt()
    {
        return $this->paidAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set insertedAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $insertedAt
     *
     * @return Invoice
     */
    public function setInsertedAt($insertedAt)
    {
        $this->insertedAt = $insertedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get insertedAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getInsertedAt()
    {
        return $this->insertedAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set client
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Client $client
     *
     * @return Invoice
     */
    public function setClient(Client $client = null)
    {
        $this->client = $client;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get client
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Client
     */
    public function getClient()
    {
        return $this->client;
    }

    /**
     * Set pdf
     *
     * @param string $pdf
     *
     * @return Invoice
     */
    public function setPdf($pdf)
    {
        $this->pdf = $pdf;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get pdf
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPdf()
    {
        return $this->getAbsolutePath().$this->pdf;
    }

    private function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return __DIR__ . '/../../../documents/invoices/';
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\InvoiceStatus $status
     *
     * @return Invoice
     */
    public function setStatus(InvoiceStatus $status = null)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\InvoiceStatus
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Add product
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\InvoiceProduct $product
     *
     * @return Invoice
     */
    public function addProduct(InvoiceProduct $product)
    {
        $this->products[] = $product;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove product
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\InvoiceProduct $product
     */
    public function removeProduct(InvoiceProduct $product)
    {
        $this->products->removeElement($product);
    }

    /**
     * Get products
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    /**
     * Get amount
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAmount()
    {
        $amount = 0;
        foreach($this->products As $product)
        {
            $amount += $product->getAmount();
        }

        return $amount;
    }

    /**
     * Set currency
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Currency $currency
     *
     * @return Invoice
     */
    public function setCurrency(Currency $currency)
    {
        $this->currency = $currency;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get currency
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Currency
     */
    public function getCurrency()
    {
        return $this->currency;
    }
}
```

My Product entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->insertedAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="label", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $label;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="decimal", scale=2)
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="inserted_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $insertedAt;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set label
     *
     * @param string $label
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setLabel($label)
    {
        $this->label = $label;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get label
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLabel()
    {
        return $this->label;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set insertedAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $insertedAt
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setInsertedAt($insertedAt)
    {
        $this->insertedAt = $insertedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get insertedAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getInsertedAt()
    {
        return $this->insertedAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param string $price
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }
}
```

My InvoiceProduct entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * InvoiceProduct
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="invoice_product")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\InvoiceProductRepository")
 */
class InvoiceProduct
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->insertedAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="decimal", scale=2)
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="quantity", type="integer")
     */
    private $quantity;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Invoice", inversedBy="products", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $invoice;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="inserted_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $insertedAt;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set quantity
     *
     * @param integer $quantity
     *
     * @return InvoiceProduct
     */
    public function setQuantity($quantity)
    {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get quantity
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getQuantity()
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }

    /**
     * Set invoice
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Invoice $invoice
     *
     * @return InvoiceProduct
     */
    public function setInvoice(Invoice $invoice)
    {
        $this->invoice = $invoice;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get invoice
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Invoice
     */
    public function getInvoice()
    {
        return $this->invoice;
    }

    /**
     * Set product
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Product $product
     *
     * @return InvoiceProduct
     */
    public function setProduct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get product
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Product
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    /**
     * Set insertedAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $insertedAt
     *
     * @return InvoiceProduct
     */
    public function setInsertedAt($insertedAt)
    {
        $this->insertedAt = $insertedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get insertedAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getInsertedAt()
    {
        return $this->insertedAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param string $price
     *
     * @return InvoiceProduct
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * Get amount
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAmount()
    {
        return $this->quantity * $this->price;
    }
}
```

My InvoiceType:

```
namespace  AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;


class InvoiceType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('createdAt', DateType::class, array(
                'widget' => 'single_text'
            ))
            ->add('client', EntityType::class, array(
                'class'    => 'AppBundle:Client',
                'choice_label' => 'contact.name'
            ))
            ->add('products', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => InvoiceProductType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true
            ))
        ;
    }
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Invoice'
        ));
    }
}
```

My InvoiceProductType:

```
namespace  AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\MoneyType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

class InvoiceProductType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('product', EntityType::class, array(
                'class'    => 'AppBundle:Product',
                'choice_label' => 'label'
            ))
            ->add('quantity', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('price', MoneyType::class)
        ;
    }
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Invoice'
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Up, i need your help guys :)

Comment: The error sounds like the property accessor has problems setting/getting some values. However, I recommend you to read this: http://blog.iltar.nl/posts/733915-avoiding-entities-in-forms

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i respected this documentation, but i don't find any error in getter/setter in my code :/

Comment: exactly, that's also what the error message points out ;)